# Using Wagtail's rich text widget for simple form?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

I created and registered a very simple email form for the Wagtail admin site without an underlying model:

```
class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(label='Betreff', max_length=100)
    body = forms.CharField(label='Nachricht', widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Now I would like to use Wagtail's rich text widget for the message body, so I did this:

```
from wagtail.admin.rich_text import DraftailRichTextArea

class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(label='Betreff', max_length=100)
    body = forms.CharField(label='Nachricht', widget=DraftailRichTextArea)
```

The widget is initialized, but an error is raised in the browser:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.draftail.initEditor')
```

What would I need to add to use the Draftail widget, and how can I transform the field's content to regular HTML in the view before sending the message (i.e. outside of a template)?

Thanks, Jan